# Is it possible to change safari scrollbar behavior?

Tags: macos, mac, html, safari

This has been driving me nuts mostly when browsing the StackExchange sites.

It's too aggressive about displaying the draggable scrollbar. If it would just hide the instant I mouse away, that'd be a major improvement, as I could then hunt for an area not over the scrollbar, to scroll with my two fingers. but on single or two lines of text it's nearly impossible to avoid, and the 2 second timeout is maddening when I just want to read the text.

Maybe there is a way to disable the scrollbars entirely?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is far from ideal, but you can force scroll bars on OSX yourself:

Go to: `System Preferences` `->` `General` `->` **`Show scroll bars:`** *`Always`*

[image]

Comment: Will it let me hide them always and forever? Doesnt look like it